# Question on Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, mathematicians

Give an example of an infinite group in which every element has a finite order

Comment: Sounds more like a command

Comment: Textbooks can give their readers commands, but real people don't give each other commands like that interpersonally. Nor should we toss verbatim quotes of textbook exercises at each other absent any form of human communication. That would be a rather strange conversation starter in real life, to walk up to your teacher, point to a question, and then just wait in silence for them to do it for you. Put your quote into a blockquote, and then talk to us. Tell us what everything - what you've tried, what your thoughts are, anything that's gone through your head that could be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

$\Bbb{Z_2 \oplus \Bbb{Z_2 \oplus \Bbb{Z_2 \oplus \dots}}}$

To make it more interesting, explore on this problem-

> If G is a finitely generated, torsion group, then is G necessarily finite?

Answer (score 0):

Take the sum of countably many copies of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, that is, the group of sequences of elements of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ that have only finitely many non-zeros. Each element in this group has order 2.

As another example, take the group $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid z = e^{2\pi i x} , x \in \mathbb{Q} \}$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. If $z = e^{2\pi i \frac{p}{q}}$, with $p$ and $q$ coprime, then $z$ has order $q$.